# Can EF7 Create non-clustered primary key?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EF6.1 we had to use migration to get a non-clustered PK. 
Does anyone know if EF7 have first-class support for non-clustered PK or do we have to use work arounds again?

Comment: Not all database providers support the concept of clustered indexes, so what's not working for you by [declaring explicit indexes](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relational/indexes.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have your answer now, since EF Core 1.0 (formerly EF7) is baked.  But just in case you didn't know or if any one else comes across this thread...

EF Core does have support within the mssql provider.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5790

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Entity Framework Core Code First by ovveriding OnModelCreating in DbContext

```
  p.HasKey(b => b.ColumnId).ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```

This will generate migration like this:

```
 table.PrimaryKey("PK_Columns", x => x.ColumnId)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", false);
```